# How can I reduce the whitespace below amp-web-push?

Tags: push-notification, amp-html

I'm noticing that the `<amp-web-push>` component includes space for both a **subscribe** and an **unsubscribe** button, but only renders one or the other depending on your setting. This leads to a gap of white space above or below the rendered button.

I also see that on iOS, where web push is not supported, both buttons show up as blank white space.

Is there any valid way in AMP to shrink the invisible web push button so it does not take up precious browser real estate?

Here's a link to reproduce the issue (you can also reference the screenshots below): https://globalnews.ca/news/7453249/us-election-biden-transition-legal/amp/

**Subscribe button doesn't render:**

[image: Unsubscribe button with white space above]

**Unsubscribe button doesn't render:**

[image: Subscribe button with white space below]

**Both buttons don't render on iOS:**

[image: Both buttons are whited out on iOS]

Comment: Why are you using two `amp-web-push-widget`? If a user is a subscriber, they would see the unsubscribe button. The current example solicits a subscription. You need to sync the server-side subscription registration process with the appropriate page.

Comment: @JayGray Just following the example on the AMP website: https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-web-push&format=websites. If the user is a subscriber, they will see the unsubcribe button and the subscribe button will be hidden. Do you have an example of this functionality working with one `<amp-web-push-widget>` button?